# Recursively generated component doesn't receive auth props, as all other components do?

Tags: reactjs

In the comment section for a project I'm working on, I recursively display comments, as replies to eachother. So I recursively render the component for a Comment, but on replies to top level comments, my auth props are not passed, despite using `constructor(props){  super(props);...`.

Here is a screengrab of the comment section, and the props that are passed: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWWjG.jpg
I can't reply to the two comments test, because as shown in the console, the props don't get passed auth. Ignore that in the screenshot im not logged in, that doesn't factor in, if I am it doesnt get passed down either.

It occurs in my onSubmit function, which posts a reply to a comment. The error only occurs when replying to a comment that is a reply to a top level comment, top level replying works fine.

- Comment 1 <- Can post this fine (gets passed auth props fine)
- - Comment 2 <- Can reply to comment 1 fine (Doesn't get passed auth props)

I am fairly new to react, so I might be doing some stuff improperly.

Ive been looking at what props are passed to the recursive components, and the auth props aren't passed to recusively generated components. Despite using all the same code obviously.

Here is where I render the nested comment:

```
{
commentJSON.replies.length > 0 &&  commentJSON.replies.map(child=>{
   return <Comment commentJSON={child} />
   })
}
```

The Constructor for Comment is

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         userComment:''
    }
}
```

And I have this at the bottom of the component:

```
Comment.propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Comment);
```

I render the top level components from the Post View component

```
 {   
    this.state.comments ? (
       commentSection.map(topLevelComment=>{                                        
          return(  <Comment commentJSON={topLevelComment}/> )
       })
   ):(
       <p>Loading Comments..</p>
   )
}
```

```
TypeError: _this.props.auth is undefined
Comment/_this.onSubmit
src/components/Post/CommentSection/Comment.js:34

  31 | onSubmit = (e) => {
  32 |     
  33 |     e.preventDefault()
> 34 |     let user = this.props.auth.user.user;
     | ^  35 |     let comment = {
  36 |         author:{
  37 |             username:user.username,
```

Comment: console.log this.props inside that component and send a screenshot

Comment: Added, thanks for looking: https://imgur.com/a/iPLjVl4

Comment: so you are getting an auth prop, but user object inside auth prop is empty.

Comment: Not quite, thats just cause I was not logged in when i took the screenshot. Heres a new one: https://imgur.com/a/aeLAWbc it doesn't make a difference if I'm logged in, cause props.auth should be passed regardless. But the two comments with the text 'test' don't get passed props, but the comment 'testing the frontend..' does. Which is why I can reply to the first comment, but can't reply to the second level ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Comment);
```

When you use Comment component outside of the file you use component connected to redux (wrapped with connect HOC), but when you use Comment component from the same file you use component which isn't connected to the redux. 
I would suggest not to connect this components to redux and set auth as a prop from parent component.

Comment: This works for me, the functionality is up. Is it bad practice to pass the user object in this way as opposed to how I was? I am not too up to par with standards and such as a lot of my web dev experience is self taught. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Brooks27, it's actually a good practice to connect to redux only top level components and pass data to the components on lower levels. It makes components like Comment more reusable, simple, and easy to test.